# How can I make an addition with the numbers of a given string in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to make an addition (+) with the numbers of a string.
I have tried to do this:

```
void add_numbers(string z)
{
    char result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(z); i++)
    {
        result = result + z[i];
    }
    printf("%c", result);
}

int main(void)
{
    string z = "2222";
    add_numbers(z);
}
```

The output should be `10`, because 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10. But, actually, the output is `]0;`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget that the string uses the ASCII representation of `'2'`, which is 50 (on most modern systems).  (Four times two is normally eight, not ten; four times fifty is two hundred.)  Also, printing `result` as a character won't yield what you expect.  And it is not clear where either the `]` or `0` comes from.  Go back to the drawing board — and use `"%d\n"` to print the result (and it would probably be more sensible to use `int result = 0;` than `char result = 0;`.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `[unsigned int]result += z[i] - '0'`; see [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: *"2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10"*   Are you sure about that?  Looks like `8` to me.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, I forgot, about ASCII, sorry for this.
Also, thanks Neil and abelenky. Math error damnnn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* string;
void add_numbers(string z)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*z)
    {
        result +=*z++-'0';  // I love the symbol sequence here: +=*z++-'0';
    }
    printf("%d", result);
}

int main(void)
{
    string z = "2222";  // Correct answer is 8
    add_numbers(z);
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.01s 5444KB
8
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/Oy2AJD)

Comment: May be worth explaining that `-'0'` subtracts the ASCII value for character `'0'` from the current ASCII digit resulting in the decimal value for that digit. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/). So, e.g., `'1' - '0' == 1`

Answer (score 1):

The variable "result" is not char. It must  be int.
[EDIT] Sure, this is ONE of the problems.

Comment: The variable `result` _is_ `char` but _should be_ `int`.  And that's only part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use char for 'result' (it is prone to UB as it will easily overflow), instead use something like int. You also cannot use the '%c' format specifier in printf, as it will print the character representation of its argument. You also have to remember the characters of a string are (not guaranteed, but most likely) stored in ASCII format, where the numerical characters do not correspond to their actual integer numbers. Subtract a '0' from each digit to accomodate for this.

```
result = result + z[i];
```

should be

```
result = result + z[i] - '0';
```

or even better

```
result += z[i] - '0';
```